# Is there any specific method for constructing the second parameter importObject of WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming()?

Tags: javascript

I want to use wasm through JavaScript written by myself.
Like that“WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch('xxx.wasm'),importObject)”.
But I have a problem with parameter “importObject”.

How can I build this parameter,importObject？
How can I build this parameter,importObject，with wasm generated by emscripten？

Comment: [The `importObject` parameter is **optional**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/JavaScript_interface/instantiateStreaming). If you don't know what to put there, do you even need it?